# How to access highlighted text from any app and use it in win form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm coding a phoning application in c# 4.5.2 and I'd like to know how can I use highlighted text from any application?

What I try to do, is to select text (phone numbers) from any application (like Chrome, Notes, Outlook, etc...) and use this to create a call.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean that in the other application (Chrome, Notes, Outlook, etc.) the phone number is clickable? When you click on the phone number it opens your application and makes a call?

Comment: @Joop Sounds more like some dictionary/translation tools, where you'd just select or point on a word, then hit a shortcut to look that up (or do the call here). I don't think this is just about implementing a "tel:" protocol handler.

Comment: @Mario Sounds reasonable. Maybe the UI Automation framework works. But, correct me if I'm wrong, the mentioned applications need to support this.

Comment: Yep, of course, you'll need some way to get the actual text, which could be as easy as determining the standard control at position X, but if that program does its own rendering, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Joop I'd like to highlight a phone number, press ctrl+y and create a call with the phone selected. I already know make the ctrl+y event.

Comment: After selecting text user must copy highlighted text to clipboard (ctrl+c). Your app get text from clipboard and process it.